# detecting coloured lines and grabing image between two coloured lines python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

[image]

I have written a python code using opencv and numpy to detect red colour lines in a video and it is working fine as it is able to detect the edges of the red lines. but i want to grab the part of the video in between each two lines as images.how to do that ?? Now  I have updated an image. i want to extract the image in between two red lines from the video.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

video = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/ksourav/AGS/SampleVideos/Trail1.mp4")

while True:
    ret, frame = video.read()

if not ret:

    video = cv2.VideoCapture("/home/ksourav/AGS/SampleVideos/Trail1.mp4")
    continue

#gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

low_red = np.array ([5, 50, 50])

up_red = np.array([10, 255, 255])

mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, low_red, up_red)

edges= cv2.Canny(mask, 100, 200, apertureSize=7, L2gradient=True)

lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 9, np.pi/180, 250, maxLineGap=70)

if lines is not None:

    for line in lines:

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[0]

        cv2.line(frame, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)


cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

key = cv2.waitKey(25)

if key == 27:

    break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: please share some sample images to illustrate what the red lines look like. What you're looking for is capturing an ROI using a `rect` object, but at best, that'll give you a smaller rectangular region

Comment: yess .. Now I have updated an image.you can go through that.